# pd.read_excel can't read xlsm file

Tags: python, excel

I use  below code to read xlsm file:

`df = pd.read_excel(filepath,target_worksheet)`

but it doesn't work, the error message is:
`XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document`.

Pandas official website mentions that it supports xlsm file,  as [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). I am wondering whether my conclusion is correct or not.

Then I use win32com , which can open the excel file and extract the data for cells, but it seems that it can't be read as DataFrames.

Is there any solution to read xlsm file to DataFrame?
Thanks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does support xlsm files.

That error often happens when you are trying to access password protected Excel files, Here you have a workaround if that's your case:

https://davidhamann.de/2018/02/21/read-password-protected-excel-files-into-pandas-dataframe/